# Error in installing Phonegap on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, node.js, cordova

When installing phonegap on my computer, I receive this error message. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
C:\Users\Scott>npm install -g phonegap 

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself 

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity. 

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin gs. 

npm ERR! network 

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'


npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200 

npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nod 
ejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap" 

npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Scott 

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29 

npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14 

npm ERR! syscall connect 

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT 

npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT 

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\Scott\npm-debug.log 

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have tried changing the registry using `C:\Users\Scott>npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"`, but I cannot resolve the error. I have tried uninstalling and re installing node.js, but that did not work either. I am working on my home network if that helps at all. I have also tried installing previous versions of phonegap with no success. I have also tried installing cordova and that has not worked either. Gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NPM cannot access the internet. If you are under cooperation network you might need to set proxy for NPM. `npm config set proxy http://your-proxy-server:your-proxy-port`. The proxy setting in IE will NOT be used by NPM you need to manually setup.

HTH.

Comment: I did what you said and now instead of etimedout, I now have a econnrefused error. Any solutions to that?